# OpenCV set color to a foreground marked pixel GC_PR_FGD

Tags: ios, image-processing, opencv, pixel, foreground

I used cv::grabCut to extract an object from an image. It runs well.

Now I've the object in a separately Mat without background, and I want to set black color to the entire object. I want to set black color to all the pixels marked with GC_PR_FGD (foreground pixels).

How can I do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [cv::grabCut documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-grabcut) it seems that you can get as an output a mask with the following values:

- GC_BGD Certainly a background pixel
- GC_FGD Certainly a foreground (object) pixel
- GC_PR_BGD Likely a background pixel
- GC_PR_FGD Likely a foreground pixel

I am assuming you want an image with the background as white and the foreground as black. In that case, you can create a new matrix and while looping through the mask pixels, you assign 0 or 1 (or 255) to that matrix, depending on the mask pixel value.

For example, assuming you have gotten a `cv::Mat mask` as the result of the algorithm, do something like (warning, I haven't compiled, it's approximate):

```
cv::Mat binaryImage = zeros(mask.rows, mask.cols, CV_8U);

for (int i==0; i<mask.rows; ++i){
    for (int j==0; j<mask.cols; ++j){
        // choose pixels that are certainly or likely background
        if (mask.at<uchar>(i,j) == GC_BGD || mask.at<uchar>(i,j) == GC_BGD){
            binaryImage.at<uchar>(i,j) = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bob, first thanks to answer fast. I've modified your code a bit. I've added binaryImage.at<uchar>(i,j) = 255; in the "if", because you write this without (i,j), but the code doesn't work. In running time never enter to "if"...

Comment: Hey Bob! Finally it works! Before the for I was doing cv::compare(output,cv::GC_PR_FGD,output,cv::CMP_EQ); that remove the flag GC_PR_FGD to each pixel. If I comment this operation, your code works! Thank you very much Bob!

Comment: @m4rkit0z You are right, I actually forgot the `i` and `j` inside the loop!! Fixing it right away. Glad it helped you